# No ringing for FaceTime, no alert sound for iMessage

Tags: ipad, messages, facetime, alert

I'm not getting ringing for FaceTime and not getting alert sounds when IMessages come in. I believe I've got all my setting right, and I can see the calls coming in if the iPad is in use. Do not disturb is not on, volume is not muted, the apps all have sound settings, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem. 
I won't know if it works 'till someone calls - but I have just found in Settings>Do Not Disturb>Allow Calls From, change to EVERYONE.

Comment: OP says Do Not Disturb is *not* on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where there was no sound notification from a FaceTime call. I found the answer at the side of the phone, a small switch for muting was turned on. It’s situated just above the volume controls. It shows a red colour when on.